# Passing constructor arguments to a Named Instance In Structure Map Where Type is Only known at Run time

Tags: structuremap, ioc-container

This is similar to the question asked at [StructureMap - Override constructor arguments for a named instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439156), but different in the respect that I don't know the type at coding time and therefore cannot use the generic form of GetInstance().

So while:

```
ObjectFactory.With(IFoo).GetInstance<IBar>("foobar");
```

will work, there is apparently no way to call:

```
ObjectFactory.With(IFoo).GetInstance(typeof(IBar), "foobar");
```

I have a workaround using a private generic method and the MakeGenericMethod() on that private method's MethodInfo.

As you might imagine, I'm not really happy with that approach, but I cannot see any other way out of the situation.

Answer (score 0):

The method you want is GetNamedInstance(), which is not available when you use the With() method.  I'm sure it would not be too hard to add it, maybe you could email Jeremy Miller and see if he can add it in StructureMap 3.  Or submit a patch :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I am actually programming to IContainer (which I gather is the preferred approach).  GetNamedInstance() isn't part of the interface.  It certainly looks as if the overloads of GetInstance() are replacing GetNamedInstance().  

I will probably do a patch, but I really want to make sure that I haven't missed something first.